# ansible variables: can you create them dynamically and then loop through them?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: lxc_hosts
  name:  get list of lxc containers on lxc host
  tasks:
  - name: get list of containers
    shell: >
      lxc-ls | awk -vRS= -vFS="\n" '//'
    register: containers
  - debug: msg="{{containers.stdout}}"
```

The debug returns values like this:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [10.1.1.1] => {
    "msg": "container1\ncontainer2\ncontainer3"
}
ok: [10.1.1.2] => {
    "msg": "container22\ncontainer23\ncontainer24"
}
```

I'm hoping there's a way to parse the results I get back into a list like this:

```
container1
container2
container3
```

and / or

```
container22
container23
container24
```

And then somehow I'd like to be able to loop through these lists and run another play against them.  Something like this:

```
shell:  lxc-attach --name={{item}}
register: attach_results
with_items:  <list of containers>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but have you looked at the LXC module instead of using shell? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lxc_container_module.html

Comment: I think the best solution is to write the small filter plugin

Comment: @arbabnazar i don't know what you mean by that.  I'm just starting out with ansible.  can you point me to a doc / link that will explain?

Comment: @smiller171 thanks.  that's good to know. i'll check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working:

```
 - debug: msg="{{containers.stdout}}"
   with_items:
     - "{{ containers.stdout.split(',')|select('match', 'container*')|list }}"
```

Comment: I don't know your exact scenario but happy that my example help you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ containers.stdout | select("match", ". container*") | list }}"
```

Comment: can you give me a bit more context around the statement so I know where to put it?  Thanks!

Comment: just use it with the debug task and found out it result that it is giving you the desired result, then you can put it where ever you want. I have updated the question

Comment: unforunately, that doesn't work. you have to split the output first... and then try the select against that.